# What should we do about tag wiki excerpts?

Tags: discussion, tags, policy

Recently, I've been going around and creating tag wiki excerpts. At first, I was wondering about the usefulness of such work-but after a few accepts, it seemed like a good idea.
After a few ([not-so](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92375)) [stupid](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92374) [blunders](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92403), I got autobanned from editing. I know, a tragedy. Please, save your gallons of tears for later, we need to focus :)

Naturally, the first thing I did was [lament in the site chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63275349#63275349). Out of the blue, [a user](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26175/sphennings) came along and pointed out that my edits were technically against the [policy for good tag excerpts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).

Now, I am pretty sure that this is part of the "default" kit assigned to all SE sites, but the point still remains.

Most of our tags are about the **content** of a question, not the **question itself.** Thus, according to the policy, there is no need for a usage guide-the exceptions are tags such as [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) and [internal-consistiency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-consistiency).

Essentially, should we even have such "boilerplate" descriptions of a topic on wiki excerpts?

Comment: As to not let your question without anything, I'll just say that I don't know. It's in part because I don't really look at them ...

Comment: @Tortliena since asking the question I saw the same behavior continue; my edits would be rejected by sphennings for being boilerplate, then L. Dutch would come along and approve them. I see reasons for both sides but we should really pick one and change the rules accordingly.

Comment: Do I understand your question? The [tag:science-fiction], [tag:science-based], [tag:hard-science] and [tag:internal-consistency] tags are unique in that they scope the *answers,* not the *questions.* They exist due to years of experience dealing with people who want varying degrees of scientific basis or, in the case of [tag:internal-consistency], help making sure the rules of their world make sense. I don't understand what you mean by "the content of a question, not the question itself."

Comment: @JBH I pointed out those tags are the *exception*. Most others refer to "the content of the question..." (e.g. questions tagged space involve, well, space.)

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "the content of a question, not the question itself."

Comment: Tags tell the reader "This question concerns Topic X"